# How to solve this equation derived from electric field geometry?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, algebraic-geometry

[This link](http://physics.oregonstate.edu/%7Eminote/COURSES/ph631/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=emch2_.pdf) shows how to calculate the electric potential of a charge outside (or inside) of a conducting spherical shell using the method of image charges. On page 3 it shows an equation:

$$\sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2-2ab\cos\theta}{a^2+d^2-2ad\cos\theta}}=\hbox{constant}$$

which comes from the fact that the potential has to equal zero for all theta. $a $ and $d$ are given by the problem and you have to solve for $b$ in order to know where to place the image charge. The solution given is $$b =\frac{a^2}{d}$$

but I don't see how they arrived at this solution. Solving this purely by algebraic manipulation was too hard for me, so I'm assuming there is an easier way to solve this. My hunch is that it has something to do with law of cosines but I'm not sure what to do.

My questions are:

> (1) how would you solve this algebraically if possible
>
> (2) how would you solve this in the most efficient way

Comment: The solution to the equation depends on the constant $k$. If you read the linked text carefully, it does not say that $b = \frac{a^2}{d}$ is *the* solution; it just says that if you take $k = \frac{a}{d}$, then the solution is $b = \frac{a^2}{d}$. For a general constant, the solution is the solution to some quadratic in $b$ that has complicated roots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given expression is constant for every value of $\theta$ (this is explained  in the linked article but maybe not so clear from the text of the question). It follows that the values it takes for $\cos\theta=1$ and $\cos\theta=-1$ must be the same, that is:
$$
{a-b\over a-d}=\pm{a+b\over a+d},
$$
which has the solutions
$$
b={a^2\over d}
\quad\hbox{and}\quad 
b=d.
$$
By substituting these into the original expression we get in both cases an expression not depending on $\theta$, so these are in fact the only solutions of our problem.

In the case at hand we know (from the linked article) that $d>a$ and $b<a$, thus only the first solution is of interest.